# How to get a node inside a page using node identifier?

Tags: aem, jcr

I want to get a node using node identifier. Right nowi'm using session to get the node i.e

```
Node node = session.getNodeByIdentifier(node.getTierIdentifier());
```

but i want to get it using Page or resource instead of session is there any method or way to get the node without session ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a JCR `Session` to do it. If you have a `Page` or a `Resource`, you may get the related `PageManager` or `ResourceResolver` and adapt them to the `Session`:

```
Session session = page.getPageManager().adaptTo(Session.class);
```

or

```
Session session = resource.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class);
```

Comment: i get the session i don't want to get the node using session i want it using page or resource and i have node identifier

Comment: I see. So it is impossible to do what you want.